# PHP checking range on a ZIP Code returns a syntax error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a form that accepts a pair of zip codes, that once entered the page will output a list of records in between them.

It works if I hard code the zip code values, but the customer file, by itself, has an error. Sort them by last name is also failing.

ZipRecord.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Find all customers between these two ranges.

<form action="Customers.php" method="get">

Beginning Zip:
<input type="text" name="Zip1">

Ending Zip:
<input type="text" name="Zip2">

<button type="sumbit">Find</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code outputs the zip codes to the user. This currently does not work and reports an error.

```
SELECT userID, FirstName, LastName, Address1, City, State,
   Zip FROM Customers WHERE Zip > AND Zip <
;No records returned:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'AND Zip <' at line 1
```

Customers.php:

```
<?php
//page 368 in text, but i prefer w3schools method, Select Data with MySQLi
require("readonly.php");

$sql = "SELECT userID, FirstName, LastName, Address1, City, State, Zip";     //dont use * to show all columns
$sql .= " FROM Customers";

//$Zip1=$_GET["Zip1"];
//$Zip2=$_GET["Zip2"];

 $sql .= " WHERE Zip > ";
//$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Zip1);
$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["Zip1"]);
$sql .= " AND Zip < ";
//$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Zip2);
$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["Zip2"]);

//$sql .= "ORDER By LastName";
 //$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["LastName"]);
$sql .=";";
echo "</p>" . $sql;

$result = $conn->query($sql); //$result is a dataset

if (!$result) {
    echo "No records returned: </p> " . mysqli_error($conn);
} else { 
    echo "Query successful.";

if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) { //if there are rows in the dataset...
//output data of each rows
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo "<form action='delete.php' method='post'>";
        echo "userID"; //you could use a table format or CSS
        // dont forget htmlentities before outputting to screen!
        echo htmlentities($row["userID"]);
        
        echo "</br>FirstName: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["FirstName"]);
        
        echo "</br>LastName: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["LastName"]);
        
        echo "</br>Address: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["Address1"]);
        
        echo "</br>City: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["City"]);
        
        echo "</br>State: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["State"]);
        
        echo "</br>Zip: ";
        echo htmlentities($row["Zip"]);
        
        echo "<input type='text' name='userID' value='";
        echo htmlentities($row["userID"]) ."'>";
        echo "<button type='Submit'>Delete</button>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</p>";
    }

} else {
    echo "No results returned";
}
}
$conn->close(); //this is not necessary because connection closes automatically
?>
```

Comment: Did you submit the form? What was the URL when submitted? This `http://erobi022.pairserver.com/Customers.php?Zip1=01915&Zip2=02128` works. If those values aren't there your SQL is invalid. You should check that the values are present before trying to use them.

Comment: You have not entered condition after the Where clause. Try initializing it with some value in your database

Comment: "WHERE zip > AND". Greater than what? "WHERE zip > 1000 AND"...

Comment: Are you sure there is data in `$_GET["Zip1"]` and `$_GET["Zip2"]`?

Comment: The form was submitted without fields populated. Voting to close.. (action is only reproducible via that scenario).

Comment: its supposed to be values in between whatever is entered in the form, i wasn't exactly sure how to code that in. That's part f why i'm here

Comment: And using get is the only way i could get the form to actually run. I'm up for any suggestions to change it though. You're supposed to be able to enter two zip codes and get what zip codes are in that range.

Comment: The only way you get the described behavior is if the fields aren't populated. Nothing wrong with using GET, just check that it is set before trying to use it.